# Pycharm Error: DLL load failed while importing qhull: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, importerror

I've been trying to run my code and it throws an Import Error that says  DLL load failed while importing qhull: The specified module could not be found.

What could be wrong, and what can I do to fix this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [While importing scipy.stats, gets 'ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55659982/while-importing-scipy-stats-gets-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too generic: there can be many reasons. My easiest and quick way to solve such class of problems (assuming you already checked the environment, and that you have relevant packages):

- remove all python cache (`.pyc` files)

and if this doesn't solve the problem do:

- copy the setting of your virtual environment (or conda environment)
- delete the virtual environment (and then move or remove the remaining files)
- create again the environment, with the packages you got from first point

Very often, with such procedures, you get again a working environment. It seems that on some updates, some files remain in the wrong place, and so the wrong version of a DLL is used, and it confuse python and windows, about inconsistent status.

Sometime you may have segmentation fault in Python program, alternate to failed to load DLL error.